# How does the Outlook app delete checkbox UI xaml code work?

Tags: windows-phone-7

If you tap on the left hand side of the screen in Outlook then an event is triggered (in this case a checkbox appears).

I would like to know the xaml on how this is achieved. It cannot be a simple "MouseLeftButtonUp" event because if you drag your finger more than a few pixels then the event does not trigger.

In my own app I am trying to get an icon appear within a listbox that has a SelectionChanged event. The issue is that if you do not touch the small icon precisely then you are triggering the listbox event rather than the event I want to occur when pressing the image.

I think I need to wrap my image in a Canvas but then am still stuck as to what the event should be.

1. How do you increase the target size of the area where a user can click on your element?
2. What event should an image have when within a listbox (which is within a pivot) that has a SelectionChanged event? (MouseLeftButtonUp causes issues if you half drag to the next pivot and lift your finger - it triggers the MouseLeftButtonUp event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented something very similar to that behavior by making an itemtemplate where the checkbox was pushed offscreen to the left by using a negative margin. 
I then created 2 visual states, one for Open and Closed. The open state set the margin to 0, bringing the checkbox back onscreen. Closed state had the negative margin.

With the fluidmove behavior, switching between states on button press was EASY. The only thing you'd have to add would be an invisible button/touch area on the left that would also trigger "opening" the checkbox column (changing state to reset the margins).

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

The outlook app is a native app, so it probably isn't using xaml at all.

If you're worried about the mouse events, then you should look at the gesture stuff in the silverlight toolkit, it contains tap, etc events that make a little more sense on the phone.

Comment: Thanks the tap event in the Silverlight control toolkit worked great! Any idea on how to make the clickable area of an image larger? I keep seeing it mentioned as "touch target area" but can't see a code example.

Comment: does image support padding?  if so, you could use padding.  or, you could put your tap event on the thing that contains the image instead of the image itself?  or use a bigger image?

Comment: Image doesn't support padding. I tried wrapping it in a button but then the button padding pushes other elements away. I'll create a more specific question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the target size and generally making stuff touchable: wrap it in a Button, then alter the ControlTemplate for the Button to remove the border.

If you look at the ControlTemplate for a Button, (Expression Blend, Edit Template, Edit a copy) you'll see the mechanics of the touch area. It's nothing more than padding/margin.

Thus, you can't bleed your touch region out without altering the layout and affecting other items around the control. I'd do two things:

- First, I'd think about whether my whole control should be larger in the first place with good spacing around it. Is my design right?
- Second, I'd cheat. I'd float a fixed sized button with no border over the area using the Translate transformation to move it around freely.

Good luck,

Luke